# How to centre the items in the last row of a grid using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Having trouble trying to align my final items in a grid layout using Tailwind (with React). Basically I want 3 items across and where there are not 3 items remaining, i.e 2 or 1, I want them centered .

I have tried some kind of col span but didn't work as intended.

To better illustrate what I am trying to do I have attached some diagrams

Current Layout:

[image: display of current layout]

Desired layout where 2 items left over :

[image: Desired layout 1]

Desired layout where 1 item left over :

[image: desired layout 2]

```html
<div className="xl:grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
 //cards .map(item) 
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consider using `flex`, `flex-wrap`, `justify-center`

**7 items:**

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-2">
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-cyan-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-cyan-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-cyan-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-cyan-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-cyan-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-cyan-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-cyan-200"></div>
</div>
```

Output:
[image]

**8 items:**

[image]

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-2">
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-cyan-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-cyan-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-cyan-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-cyan-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-cyan-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-cyan-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-cyan-200"></div>
  <div class="h-40 w-60 bg-cyan-200"></div>
</div>
```

Play around using [tailwind-css playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/as3618znvp)

Comment: My thoughts as well! If you with some calc and "arbitrary values" like `w-[calc(33.333%_-_4px)] aspect-square` after an exact `gap-[4px]` [you can even get](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Ds348MHpzF) the setup with square items. - A grid for the OP's situation will be very hard, because the hardest edge case is not really a _grid_ anymore.

Comment: @Jeroen, I agree with you , I wanted to keep it simple so didn't include `w-[calc(33.333%_-_4px)]`, that is a great and perfect approach for his problem.

Comment: redacted my comments as had an issue where i have 3 different images for the cards (repeated per name) but each image is actually a different size , having set an exact w to the image(rather than w-full) and then adding w-60 ,fixes my issue. Calc also worked however ran into issues with sizing of the cards where content is not the same